# jQuery remove DropZone.js thumbnail after deleting file

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

We have more option into `DropZone.js` such as `removedFile`. In this Javascript script, I try to remove `DropZone` thumbnail after deleting file from server. Removing file from server works fine, but I can't detach thumbnails

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var DropzoneUp = function () {
        var _componentDropzone = function () {
            if (typeof Dropzone == 'undefined') {
                console.warn('Warning - dropzone.min.js is not loaded.');
                return;
            }
            // Multiple files
            Dropzone.options.dropzoneMultiple = {
                paramName: "file",
                //...
                params: {
                    prefixFile: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                },
                removedfile: function (file) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        //...
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

        };
        return {
            init: function () {
                _componentDropzone();
            }
        }
    }();
    DropzoneUp.init();
</script>
```

How can I do that and how can I remove thumbnails?

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by this code in `success` call back function:

```js
removedfile: function (file) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        //...
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            let _ref;
            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
        }
    });
},
```